# Changing Form background color rapidly & randomly

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write some code to quickly change the background of the form to random RGB colors, but the program seems to stop presumably until the loop is complete and then it changes color once.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num1 = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        int num2 = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        int num3 = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(num1, num2, num3);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
}
```

Which part did i miss, or what did i use incorrectly?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the values in your loop, else there will always be the same. Also, Refresh your component after changing its backcolor.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        num1 = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        num2 = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        num3 = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(num1, num2, num3);
        this.Refresh();
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

However, as pointed out by Patrick Hofman, your UI thread will be locked in this loop and your form will look frozen.

A first way to solve this is to call

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

instead of `Refresh()`

but it's not the best solution.

The good solution would be to put your loop in another thread :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(ChangeBackColor);
    Thread T = new Thread(ts);
    T.Start();
}

private void ChangeBackColor()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        num1 = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        num2 = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        num3 = rnd.Next(0, 255);
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(num1, num2, num3));
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `Refresh`, you will still lock the app. Use another thread to sleep.

Comment: Oh yeah, should have put the randomise part obviously in the loop.
I've just recoded this part in 5 minutes and didnt even notice since i tried it previously yesterday for like an hour and couldnt figure out why it didnt work. 
The Refresh part is what i was missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MateuszR As commented, don't use `Refresh`. It will stall your application for the time you are executing this code!

Comment: @MateuszR It this solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as the answer. However Patrcik Hofman is right, while in the loop, you won't be able to use the graphical user interface anymore, because the graphical thread will be locked in the loop and won't take in any use interaction.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Could you give me an example how you would solve this problem then? Thanks

Comment: See the post linked at the top of your question. @MateuszR

Comment: @PatrickHofman Will do. Thank you

Comment: @PatrickHofman update my answer, is that better ?

Comment: Much better...!